# Right Outer Join with OR condition and Null in where clause -SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have two `tables`

`table1` and `table2`

I have a query as below

```
select val1, val2 , val3
FROM table1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
table2 
on ( table1.key = table2.key)
AND (table2.val1 IN (select val1 from data where datadate between @stdate and @enddate) or (table2.val1= 0 and table2.val2 =5))
WHERE table2.key IS NULL
```

This query ran very slowly

So I tried to optimize it in  below way

```
with cte 
as
(
select key
from table2
where
(table2.val1 IN (select val1 from data where datadate between @stdate and @enddate) or (table2.val1= 0 and table2.val2 =5))
)


select val1, val2 , val3
FROM table1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
cte
on ( table1.key = cte.key)

WHERE cte.key IS NULL
```

Still the query performance not improved much. So I tried to replace `OR clause` in Cte with Union. It improves the query `performance` but gave different results.

```
with cte 
as
(
select key
from table2
Inner join data
on ( data.val1 = table2.val1)
union
select key
from
table2 where val1 = 0 and val = 5

)

select val1, val2 , val3
FROM table1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
cte
on ( table1.key = cte.key)

WHERE cte.key IS NULL
```

Is it a right approach to replace `OR clause` with `UNION` ? Also, in `WHERE` `clause` there is `NULL` condition to eliminate all records from `LEFT table`. So, Adding the `OR` clause during `Join` will have any effects?

Comment: I don't understand your query, first, what is `AND(table2.val1 (...` ? it doesn't make sense it compiles. Second, what is that `val1` you are selecting from `data` ? Only 1 record returns from there? In your third query, where did `table1` go ?

Comment: Your UNION is different query to the others, it selects all records that join on data.val1 = table2.val1, plus the other records.  In your first query the ON condition uses an AND though, not an OR - so it can't be the same as far as I can see

Comment: @Sagi I missed the IN clause in the query. Data table returns multiple records...I have edited the question

Comment: Try adding or improving your indexes, that could help a lot more than moving query parts back and forth.

Comment: In short... you might find that converting your `IN` to `EXISTS` might improve things... or it might not. Only way to tell is observe the query plan. In fact if you want to troubleshoot performance you must learn some basics about query plans. Press CTRL-L and watch and learn.

Comment: Most people find `LEFT JOIN` hard enough to get, and `RIGHT JOIN` utterly confusing. Switch to LEFT JOIN - because it's much easier to understand "main table left join optional data" instead of "optional data right join main table".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write the original query as:

```
SELECT val1, val2, val3
FROM table2 t2 LEFT JOIN
     table1 t1
     ON t1.key = t2.key AND
        (t2.val1 IN (select val1 from data where datadate between @stdate AND @enddate) OR
        (t2.val1 = 0 and t2.val2 = 5))
WHERE t2.key IS NULL;
```

Written like this, the query is rather strange.  Why?  The main join condition includes `t2.key`.  When it is `NULL`, then there can be no match in `t1`.  So, the query seems to be equivalent to something like this:

```
SELECT val1, val2, val3
FROM table2 t2 
WHERE ( t2.val1 IN (select val1 from data where datadate between @stdate AND @enddate) OR
        (t2.val1 = 0 and t2.val2 = 5)
      ) AND
      t2.key IS NULL;
```

(Note:  Depending on where the `SELECT` columns come from, you might need to replace these with `NULL`.)

If you have misstated the query in your question, then you should ask *another* question with the correct query.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking when I saw the query.

Comment: This is actually an existing stored proecudure for  a report. I knew that t2.key = NULL will eliminate all the t2 table rows. But, since the Join clause have OR condtion to fetch data from t2 table I was confused. So this and clause with OR condition is irrelevant here?

Comment: @bmsqldev . . . The `or` is the second condition on the `JOIN`.  The `key` comparison is still the primary comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting different result as you have missing date criteria in your where condition:

```
select val1 from data where datadate between @stdate and @enddate
```

Try below sql:

```
with cte 
as
(
select key
from table2
Inner join data
on ( data.val1 = table2.val1 and datadate between @stdate and @enddate)
union
select key
from
table2 where val1 = 0 and val = 5

)

select val1, val2 , val3
FROM table1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
cte
on ( table1.key = cte.key)

WHERE cte.key IS NULL
```